# Adding line to sudoers.d with tee not working

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, tee

I need to make a user able to reload php-fpm.

When i run below code to append below line via tee from the root user nothing happens except i enter insert mode (lines with `>` ) that i can only close with a `"`. Seems like a syntax error but i don't see it.

```
echo "myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service php7.2-fpm reload" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/php-fpm > /dev/null
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: "insert mode (lines with `>`)" means there are unbalanced quotation marks or an unfinished control structure, neither of which I see here. Is it possible that you have 2 single quotes rather than a double quote in one of the 2 places that you show `"`?

Comment: Thanks! After looking a long time in my terminal i saw that it was not closed because of the difference in characters " and  “.

Comment: Your original question had `"` and `"` in it, not `"` and `“`. If you can cut and paste exactly what you have it makes it easier for us to help you. (I did cut and paste what you wrote into the `hd` program to see exactly what you had).

Comment: Makes sense - i will remember to copy directly from the terminal next time!

Answer (score 1):

For some obscure reason the `"` had turned into a `“` in my terminal. I have no idea where that happened as i never use that character myself. 
Thanks to icarus for the lead!